# can 3D transition be applied when starting another activity?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

i was checking on the android api demo and i came across the 3D transition that takes from one VIEW to another, so i'm wondering if it can be applied on activities?

Comment: U mean 3d rotation of layouts? am I right.

Comment: well in the api demos it's under API Demos>views>animation>3D Transition.. yeah it's the one where the listview rotates and then displays images..and i want to apply it on the whole activity

Comment: I posted the answer and for me its working for layouts also, If u get any difficulty feel free to ask:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can apply 3d transition  for layouts/activities also. check this tutorial, this will help u 
Remember this example works for imageviews and u shd do it for layouts.

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html